# How to count multiple lines from git log in PowerShell?

Tags: git, powershell, git-log

**PROBLEM**

```
git log --pretty=oneline $branch...$version
```

Allows me to determine how many commits are between the specified branch and tag. Each commit is printed to the console window on a different line, and starts with 40 characters of that commit's SHA and is followed by a brief description.

Using PowerShell, I would like to take the count of all these commits and assign it to a variable. I don't want to output this data to a file.

My assumption is that a large regex would be the best option, but I'm thinking that there must be an easier solution.

**QUESTION**
Is there an easier way to find the count of multiple lines outputted to the console?

Also, is there a way to get around the buffer size when handling the log data without adjusting the buffer-size of the console window? Or is this a factor I will need to worry about at all? (*when handling a large amount of commits*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```powershell
(git log --oneline $branch...$version | Measure-Object -Line).Lines
```

This will give you the raw number, which you can assign to a variable. You won't need to worry about pagination with a large number of commits; Git disables pagination when the output is being piped.

Answer (score 2):

Scott's version works fine, but you could also do it like this:

```
(git log --oneline $branch...$version).length
```

if you need to filter the output, use select-string with a regex, e.g:

```
(git log ... | select-string "^commit ").length
```